# Display single db value in msgbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-office

I have the following vba code in an access 2007 file:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim a As String
Dim b As DAO.Recordset

a = " select col1 from table1 where id = 1 "
Set b = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(a)

MsgBox (b)
b.Close

End Sub
```

But I am getting the following error on the `MsgBox (b)` line.  Any idea why that's happening?  The query returns a single value, which I want to display in a message box.

Comment: The `MsgBox` takes `String` (or string-convertible such as `Integers`, `Longs`) as input; I think `b` is not a `String` but an object `DAO.RecordSet`. You should get the recordset result into a string before to show it through `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `MsgBox` to display the value contained in the first column of your recordset, you can do it this way ...

```vb
MsgBox b(0)
```

However, you don't really need to open a recordset to retrieve that single value.  You could use a `DLookup` expression instead.

```vb
MsgBox DLookup("col1", "table1", "id = 1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Matteo mentioned you need to pass a String or something that can be converted to a String to MsgBox. In this case you can specify the field in your select query.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim a As String
    Dim b As DAO.Recordset

    a = " select col1 from table1 where id = 1 "
    Set b = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(a)

    MsgBox b.Fields("col1")  ' Msgbox b("col1") should also work
    b.Close

End Sub
```